# Export products with Category Names

Tags: php, arrays, magento

I'm exporting categories associated to a product which is an array. It's working fine for static indexes as follow:

```
foreach($collection as $product) {
    $_cat = array();
    $categoryName = array();    
    foreach ($product->getCategoryIds() as $Id) {
        $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($Id);
        $categoryName[] = $_cat->getName();
    }
    fputcsv(
        $output, 
        array(
            $categoryName[0] . $categoryName[1] . $categoryName[2]
        )
    );
}
```

When I'm trying to give indexes dynamically using `foreach()` or `for()` loop, products are not being exported. For example, if I'm using

```
fputcsv(
    $output, 
    array(
        foreach($categoryName as $name) { 
            echo $name;
        }
    )
);
```

it's not working.

Also I've tried

```
fputcsv($output, 
    array(
        array_value($categoryName);
    )
);
```

But it prints output `Array` whereas I'm looking for those array values as output.

Comment: I think implode() should do the job. http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: @Typoheads: Oh, How I've missed that ? If you put it in answer section I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `implode()` to prepare the array values for your needs.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php